# How to call a specific row with pandas on a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file `datasheet.csv` -

```
City  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1     -----------VALUES------------       
2     -----------VALUES------------   
3     -----------VALUES------------   
4     -----------VALUES------------ 
5     -----------VALUES------------
6     -----------VALUES------------
```

Right now I store this with this code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datasheet.csv')
```

I am able to call columns with.

```
df['City'],df['G']
```

But im not so sure on how to procede with rows.
Right now I have the code.

```
(df.loc[df['City']=='1'])
```

This prints the rows but im not able to use index to get any spesific value.
For example when I do

```
print((df.loc[df['City']=='1'])[0])
```

It returns a error "key error: 0".
Im not sure how to procede from here

Comment: You can directly use `df.loc[0]` or `df.loc[1]` for accessing rows by `index`.

Comment: Hmm, yea I did that originally but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: `df.loc` is as efficient as it gets. Maybe if there's something really specific that you are trying to do, update the question with exact requirement, sample input and expected output in that case.